# Two different definitions of independence of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I was taught that two random variables $X,Y$ are independent when the induced sigma fields $X^{-1}(\mathscr{B})$ and $Y^{-1}(\mathscr{B})$ are made up with independent events.

Now I'm following some course in cryptography where they seem to take the definition of independence as being $P[X=x,Y=y] = P[X=x]P[Y=y]$

My question is are these equivalent?

Also I wanted to know what's the situation for mutual independence. Should I work with induced sigma field or with points.

Comment: They're equivalent when $(X,Y)$ is discrete.

Comment: @StefanHansen which is the same as saying that X and Y are discrete?

Comment: Yes @Rodrigo.$\,$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, $X=x$ and $Y=y$ do represent the *atomic* events within the sigma fields of two *discrete* random variables, and $\forall x\in\Bbb R\,\forall y\in\Bbb R:P[X=x,Y=y]=P[X=x]P[Y=y]$ is the statement that *all* such events are independent, then yes, your two definitions are *essentially* equivalent.

To be more complete your cryptography textbook should say that *any* two random variables are independent iif: $$\forall\mathrm A\subseteq \Bbb R~ \forall\mathrm B\subseteq \Bbb R~:~ \mathsf P(X\in\mathrm A, Y\in\mathrm B)=\mathsf P(X\in\mathrm A)\,\mathsf P(Y\in\mathrm B)$$

Comment: All measurable subsets, not just subsets.